# List all running workflows (Workflow Foundation)

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

In Workflow Foundation, is it possible to get list of all running instances of some workflow (which is hosted as WCF service)? Let's say I would like to show a dashboard with all workflows currently active. Is there some support in the framework itself?